# IE event don't catch element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm writing a script which prevents form clicking, but i can't make it work in IE7 - 8, maby anyone know why it is?

I try to use ev = e || window.event; but nothing good happens.
Please help, and thanks in future.

```
(function( button ) {
    $( document ).click(function( e ) {
        ev = e || event;
        var clickedEl = ev.srcElement || ev.target;
        var parentClass = $( button ).attr( 'class' ).split(' ')[0];

        if ( clickedEl !== button && $( clickedEl ).parents( '.' + parentClass ).
length == 0 && !$( clickedEl ).hasClass( parentClass ) ) {

            // DO SOMETHING
        }
    });
})($('.category_select')[0]);
```

Comment: You might want to point ont in what regard it's not working. What error message are you receiving? You could also make sure to log your values at each operation, to see that they are what you expect. Is the value of `ev` what you expect? (if it isn't, we don't have to care about anything that comes after) Is the value of `clickedEl` what you expect? (If it is, we don't have to care about the value of `ev`, if it isn't, we don't have to care about anything that comes after). Is the value of `$(button).attr('class');` what you expect?

Comment: Is ev = e || event; the same as ev = e || **window**.event; ?

Comment: David: Yes, I tried to debuging, clickedEl is undefined I think the problem is that ev variable is not correct, i can't find why. i need clear explanation in future. 
@cohadar i think that event == window.event, because it's global window events and do the same :? but it's not bad to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using jQuery, an event object will be passed to the callback, regardless of the browser. Though it's important to note that you won't be receiving the *"pure"* event object: it's wrapped in a jQuery object. To get the *true* event object, do this:

```
var trueEvent = e.originalEvent;
```

That should do the trick, mind you: you won't have the jQuery `stopPropagation` method in IE8, you'll have to correct for that manually by using `.returnValue = false` and `.cancelBubble = true`

```
(function( button )
{
    $( document ).click(function( e )
    {
            var ev = e.originalEvent,//this is all you need to do, plus ev is a variable, declare it as such, 
            clickedEl = ev.srcElement || ev.target,//separate var declarations by comma
            parentClass = $( button ).attr( 'class' ).split(' ')[0];
            if ( clickedEl !== button && $( clickedEl ).parents( '.' + parentClass ).length == 0 && !$( clickedEl ).hasClass( parentClass ) )
            {
                // DO SOMETHING
            }
    });
})($('.category_select')[0]);
```

That should work
I also had a look at the jQuery reference [this is what it says on the jQuery event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)

Comment: hmm, interesting, but I'm not clearly understand what do you mean. So you said that if i try to reach `$().bind('',function(e){});`
So to get true event i need to set it as: `var trueEvent = e[0]` , and it will work cross all browser?

Comment: jQuery actually creates an event handler for you, that does all the X-browser stuff (`e = e || window.event` and what have you), and then does something like (`yourCallback.apply(this,[$(e)])`<-- pass the event as jQuery object), to get the actual object from a jQuery object, just get the element at index 0, (try `$('*')[0]`, it'll return the first node of the DOM: the jQuery object is nothing but a wrapper object with tons of methods

Comment: okay, i understand it but this thing did not solve my problem, i update my question, i will include an example. So you could see what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @GomatoX: I copy-pasted your code, and just added the `var ev = e[0]` to make it work as expected. If you're still stuck, set up a fiddle and I'll take a look

Comment: I prepared a fiddle, and figure out that it's everything all right, so i think it's something else... http://jsfiddle.net/GomatoX/8Z2xs/
Thanks man ;)

Comment: @GomatoX: I had a look at your fiddle (well, I added a console.log(e) line... as it turns out `e[0]` won't work, but you _do_ have a jQuery.Event object on your hands. To get to the _real_ event: `e.originalEvent` is what you need. Will edit my answer to reflect on that